# Ant copy task thinks absolute paths are in local directory

Tags: ant, absolute-path

I have a snippet of a file copy that looks like this:

```
<echo message="Root = ${original.src.root}" />
<copy todir="${source.root}">
    <fileset dir="${original.src.root}"/>
</copy>
```

Now, let's say that `${source.root}` is `"d:/build/src"` and `${original.src.root}` is `"d:/projects/myproj/src"`.

I get a message that says `D:\projects\myproj\scripts\build.xml:224: D:\projects\myproj\scripts\"D:\projects\myproj\src" does not exist.

Well of course I don't have a src directory in my scripts directory. When I do the echo message, it says my `original.src.root` variable is properly set. So why would it be trying to reference the basedir for an absolute path?

Answer (score 5):

Absolute paths on Windows are only treated as absolute paths if they start with a letter followed by a colon, for example `D:/mydir`. If it is enclosed in quotes, like `"D:/mydir"`, it will not see an absolute path.